# How do I detect whether include(SomeModule) will work?

Tags: cmake

I'm using a library which may or may not export *SomeModule.cmake*. If it exists, I want to use it for its better capabilities, but otherwise, I want to use a simple workaround.

However, if `include(SomeModule)` fails, CMake fails immediately with the message:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:42 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    SomeModule
```

How do I detect whether `include(SomeModule)` will work without manually intervening?

---

I'm picturing something like this:

```cmake
# this function doesn't exist:
detect_include_exists(SomeModule)

if(SomeModule_FILE_EXISTS)
  include(SomeModule)

  # call the functions inside of SomeModule
else()
  # workaround code
endif()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command [include](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/include.html) support *OPTIONAL* argument for ignore absent files. Using it with RESULT_VARIABLE you may check whether `include()` has actually included the file or not:

```
include(SomeModule OPTIONAL RESULT_VARIABLE SomeModule_Found)
if(NOT SomeModule_Found)
     # Include file is absent. Need some workaround.
endif()
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't think to check the documentation for `include`.